# Ionic 2 firebase + anguarfire2 android device not showing up the facebook auth popup

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using ionic 2 to build an app and i am having a login system in it. i am using firebase and angularfire2 to connect to firebase and use the auth system provided with firebase. below is the code i use for facebook auth.

```
  loginwithfacebook() {
    this.angfire.auth.login({
    provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
    method: AuthMethods.Popup
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log('Login Success with facebook' + JSON.stringify(response));
      let currentuser = {
        email: response.auth.displayName,
        picture: response.auth.photoURL
      };
      window.localStorage.setItem('currentuser', JSON.stringify(currentuser));
      this.navCtrl.push(Dashboard);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

this works fine in browser when i run `ionic serve` but when i test it in my android 5.0 using `ionic run android --device` when i click on the button saying "login with facebook" the popup doesnt come. i tried using `cordova add plugin inappbrowser` but a popup comes and closes and doesnt work. i also tried `crosswalk` , and the app closes when i click on the button. how do i fix this?

Comment: Firebase 3.x now supports OAuth sign in for Cordova: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the cordova-plugin-facebook4 to get this working in your mobile device.

Kindly refer the instructions [here](http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-firebase-authentication-ii/).